# Illegal processing instruction target ("xml"); when tried to build the app

Tags: android

After to add some xml files to "res folder" and tried to run the project the above problem Appear. some idea what does happen?

Comment: how you add ???

Answer (score 10):

ok, i had add two times the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` instruction in the same xml file, that was the problem.